# recursive generalized continued fraction from a single list in Python

Tags: python, recursion

I need to write a `recursive function` that takes a list `L` (of odd length) representing a generalized continued fraction, and returns the corresponding rational number.

The reason the list `L` is always odd, is the rational needs to be created by the continued fraction

```py
L[0] + L[1]/(L[2] + L[3]/L[....]))
```

i've seen this as two lists a,b. Essentially in this case the a is L[even] and the b is L[odd]

My base case is when it gets down to the last 3

```py
if n == 3: #base case
    return L[0] + (L[1] / L[2])
```

I am not sure how to advance both the numerator and the denominator in the recursion.
I keep trying things like (GCF2R is the function) (L is the list) (n = len(L))

```py
if n > 3:
    return L[0] + (L[n-2] / GCF2R(L[0:n]))
```

but since the recursion is only happening in the denominator the numerator doesn't change with each recursion.

I know I am missing some fundamental step. Any help in understand much appreciated

Comment: Show us your function's code, please.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the form of a generalized continued fraction, you can see the substructure:

```
                  L[1]
L[0] + --------------------------
                         L[3]
         L[2] +  -------------------
                               L[5]
                   L[4] +  ---------------
                                ...
```

Basically, a GCF is either an integer, or an expression of the form `a + b/c`, where `a` and `b` are integers and `c` is itself a GCF.

From that, the recursion follows naturally:

```
def GCF2R(L):
    if len(L) == 1:
        return L[0]
    else:  # Assume len(L) > 2
        return L[0] + L[1]/GCF2R(L[2:])
```

Remove the first two elements, and recurse on the rest.

Comment: Thank you!!! That was a small piece of the puzzle, and now it all works. I am still trying to understand the recursion. It seems like magic. I need to step through a few lists and keep track of what it's doing. Thanks again!

Comment: A professor of mine always said "Trust your recursion". The point of `GCF2R` is to compute the value of a continued fraction. Both `L` and `L[2:]` represent continued fractions, so the same function can be used for both. The key is to recognized that you *define* `GCF2R` once, but make multiple distinct *calls* to the same function. The computer keeps track, like for all functions, of which is the active function call and which call to return to once the active function completes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to peel these off of the end, rather than off of the front:

```
def GCF2R(L):
    if len(L) == 1:
        return L[0]
    else:
        return L[-2]/L[-1] + GCF2R(L[:-2])
```

I suppose if you passed the length, you wouldn't need to cut a new list every time:

```
def GCF2R(L,N):
    if N == 1:
        return L[0]
    else:
        return L[N-2]/L[N-1] + GCF2R(L,N-2)
```